Can not install latest version of PIP package
I'm trying to install the latest version of pyworkforce in my virtual environment, but for some reasons it installs an old version:
% python3 -m venv venv
% source venv/bin/activate
% pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir pyworkforce
Collecting pyworkforce
  Downloading pyworkforce-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (10 kB)
Collecting numpy>=1.23.0 (from pyworkforce)
  Downloading numpy-2.2.0-cp313-cp313-macosx_14_0_arm64.whl.metadata (62 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pyworkforce to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting pyworkforce
  Downloading pyworkforce-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (10 kB)
  Downloading pyworkforce-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.2 kB)
  Downloading pyworkforce-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.3 kB)
  Downloading pyworkforce-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.2 kB)
  Downloading pyworkforce-0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.3 kB)
  Downloading pyworkforce-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.9 kB)
  Downloading pyworkforce-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
Downloading pyworkforce-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (4.5 kB)
Installing collected packages: pyworkforce
Successfully installed pyworkforce-0.1.1

Can someone explain what happens here? I expect PIP to install version 0.5.1 (and whatever numpy version is needed for that), but it gives me 0.1.1.

What version of python are you using?

Not what pip version, what python version? python --version

Using Python 3.13.1 with PIP 24.3.1

Ah I get the right version when using Python 3.12. So only version 0.1.1 of Pyworkforce (and it's dependencies) is compatible with 3.13?

pyworkforce-0.1.1 didn't specify any dependencies yet, that is why pip deems it compatible

What if you just tried pip install pyworkforce except if you're on docker or similar containers

I was using Python 3.13 but only a very early version of the PyWorkforce package was compatible with that (currently very recent) Python version. In my case it was fine to switch to Python 3.12, so I've fixed it that way.
python3.12 -m venv venv

